# Does OpenFileDialog work with BindingSource?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, openfiledialog, bindingsource

I want to open a txt file with OpenFileDialog and add it to an datagridview in windows form.

I also want to use BindingSource because I have to add new data to the existing and loaded datagridview txt file from another Form using a button and some textboxes and the data given by the user in the textbox should be added to the datagridview to the existing txt file.

Here is my code of the input button event but I have no idea how to get started with another form and binding the data

```
public void input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    ofd.ShowDialog();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
    //Set the Columns or fill it with a DataAdapter
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Display", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Capacity", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Processor", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Operation System", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Released", typeof(string));

    dgvBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    dgvBindingSource.DataSource = dt;
    datagridview.DataSource = dgvBindingSource;
    dt.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Presumably its best to forget about DataTable. Create a Class with simple Properties that represents your Data. Then create a List<T> of that class and just bind it to your BindingSource. Then have a look at Serializers for example the JsonSerializer and how to serialize/deserialize the List<T> into or from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is what you're looking for

```
 public void input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
 OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        ofd.ShowDialog();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
        //Set the Columns or fill it with a DataAdapter
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Display", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Capacity", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Processor", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Operation System", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Released", typeof(string));

        // Create Line with vars from Form to Write in the TxT File
        string LineAdd =
            TextBoxID.Text + ";" + //Write Var ID;
            TextBoxName.Text + ";" + //Write Var Name;
            TextBoxDisplay.Text + ";" + //Write Var Display;
            TextBoxColor.Text + ";" + //Write Var Color;
            TextBoxCapacity.Text + ";" + //Write Var Capacity;
            TextBoxProcessor.Text + ";" + //Write Var Processor;
            TextBoxOS.Text + ";" + //Write Var Operation;
            TextBoxReleased.Text + //Write Var Released;
            "\n"; // Create New Line And Finish Line

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(ofd.FileName, LineAdd); //Add the line in File

        string[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName); // Open the txt file
        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++) //Loop for write values in DataTable
        {
            string[] line = file[i].Split(Char.Parse(";")); //Separates the vars using ";" Char
            dt.Rows.Add(line); //Add All vars in the DataTable
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dt.Dispose();
    }}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).